# Inverse Kinematics in Arkit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, scenekit, arkit

I have Scenekit model with 4 joints.

[image]

When I use it in SCNView with the code below and change the position of the parent node (Joint) I can see it animated according to the joints.

```
  private lazy var scene: SCNScene = {

        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ears")! 

        return scene
    }()
```

in viewDidLoad

```
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()

        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 5)

        rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        scnView.scene = scene
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
        scnView.backgroundColor = .white


        let joint = contentNode!.childNode(withName: "Joint", recursively: true)!
        var ik:SCNIKConstraint = .inverseKinematicsConstraint(chainRootNode: joint)
        joint.childNode(withName: "head", recursively: true)!.constraints = [ik]
```

The problem occurs when I use the same model in Arkit. In this case, I use a separate View Controller than above. I place it on the head. The model collapse when I show it in Arkit with the code below. I expect it to track head movement and bend according to it.

[image]

```
     func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
      guard let sceneView = renderer as? ARSCNView,
        anchor is ARFaceAnchor else { return nil }

    faceGeometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: sceneView.device!)!

    contentNode = SCNReferenceNode(named: "art/ears")
    //contentNode!.physicsBody = .kinematic()

    let joint = contentNode!.childNode(withName: "Joint", recursively: true)!
    var ik:SCNIKConstraint = .inverseKinematicsConstraint(chainRootNode: joint)
    joint.childNode(withName: "head", recursively: true)!.constraints = [ik]
    return contentNode
    }
```

I have this extension

```
extension SCNReferenceNode {
    convenience init(named resourceName: String, loadImmediately: Bool = true) {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: resourceName, withExtension: "scn", subdirectory: "Models.scnassets")!
        self.init(url: url)!
        if loadImmediately {
            self.load()
        }
    }
```

Normal look of model is like this
[image]

Correctly applied inverse kinematics snapshot
[image]

I tried setting setMaxAllowedRotationAngle(between 20-45 degrees) to the joints, this prevents collapse behavior but it also prevents bending.
y property of model gravity is -9.8, x and z are 0.

What might be the problem that I can't create the same effect in Arkit?